# Performance repercussions for on demand Postgres temp views

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, view

What are the performance impact on creating views on demand in Postgres?

Say I have a couple of read-only (append-only) tables, where every updates to a record is done by creating a new record (with the updated values merged with the original values).

In order to view the latest records, I would **create a temporary view for every read request**. These requests would be indirectly triggered by every REST API request to read the latest record of this entity.

This already sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: This is not necessary. All views in Postgres are 'on demand'. As a view is [actually a Query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createview.html). Just write the query in such a way that it returns only the latest rows.

Comment: Creating a view for every request seems rather useless. Just run that SELECT statement.